# Wx.choice doesn't work in ubuntu

Tags: wxpython

I speak only spanish, i will try to write in my poor english, sorry.

I'm learning wx.Python and i write a small example in Windows XP and run perfect, but the same code in ubuntu Jaunty don't work well.

The fonts of wx.Choice appear desfased and the options are barely visible, when you chosee one, the Label is always empty.

hxxp://ricardonarvaja.info/WEB/OTROS/BOA%20CONSTRUCTOR%20PASO%20A%20PASO/instantanea1.png

```
enter code here
#Boa:Frame:Frame1

import wxversion
wxversion.select('2.8')
import wx

print wx.version()
def create(parent):
    return Frame1(parent)

[wxID_FRAME1, wxID_FRAME1BUTTON1, wxID_FRAME1CHOICE1, wxID_FRAME1PANEL1, 
 wxID_FRAME1TEXTCTRL1, wxID_FRAME1TEXTCTRL2, 
] = [wx.NewId() for _init_ctrls in range(6)]

class Frame1(wx.Frame):
    def _init_sizers(self):
        # generated method, don't edit
        self.boxSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(orient=wx.VERTICAL)

    def _init_ctrls(self, prnt):
        # generated method, don't edit
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, id=wxID_FRAME1, name='', parent=prnt,
              pos=wx.Point(473, 288), size=wx.Size(364, 190),
              style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, title='Frame1')
        self.SetClientSize(wx.Size(356, 156))

        self.panel1 = wx.Panel(id=wxID_FRAME1PANEL1, name='panel1', parent=self,
              pos=wx.Point(0, 0), size=wx.Size(356, 156),
              style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        self.textCtrl1 = wx.TextCtrl(id=wxID_FRAME1TEXTCTRL1, name='textCtrl1',
              parent=self.panel1, pos=wx.Point(40, 16), size=wx.Size(100, 21),
              style=0, value=u'')
        self.textCtrl1.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.OnTextCtrl1SetFocus)

        self.textCtrl2 = wx.TextCtrl(id=wxID_FRAME1TEXTCTRL2, name='textCtrl2',
              parent=self.panel1, pos=wx.Point(40, 48), size=wx.Size(100, 21),
              style=0, value=u'')
        self.textCtrl2.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.OnTextCtrl2SetFocus)

        self.button1 = wx.Button(id=wxID_FRAME1BUTTON1, label=u'SUMAR',
              name='button1', parent=self.panel1, pos=wx.Point(140, 101),
              size=wx.Size(75, 23), style=0)
        self.button1.Center(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton1Button,
              id=wxID_FRAME1BUTTON1)

        self.choice1 = wx.Choice(choices=['suma', 'resta', 'mult'],
              id=wxID_FRAME1CHOICE1, name='choice1', parent=self.panel1,
              pos=wx.Point(160, 40), size=wx.Size(146, 21), style=0)
        self.choice1.Bind(wx.EVT_CHOICE, self.OnChoice1Choice,
              id=wxID_FRAME1CHOICE1)

        self._init_sizers()

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self._init_ctrls(parent)

    # XXX Este codigo esta sin terminar
    def OnButton1Button(self, event):

        print self.choice1.Label
        try:
            if self.choice1.Label=='suma':
                suma=int(self.textCtrl1.Value)+int(self.textCtrl2.Value)
                self.button1.Label='Suma = ' + str(suma)
            if self.choice1.Label=='resta':
                suma=int(self.textCtrl1.Value)- int(self.textCtrl2.Value)
                self.button1.Label='Resta = ' + str(suma)
            if self.choice1.Label=='mult':
                suma=int(self.textCtrl1.Value) * int(self.textCtrl2.Value)
                self.button1.Label='Mult = ' + str(suma)
        except:
            self.button1.Label='Error tipo de datos'
            self.textCtrl1.Value=''
            self.textCtrl2.Value=''

        event.Skip()

    def OnTextCtrl1SetFocus(self, event):
        self.textCtrl1.Value=''
        print self.choice1.Label
        if self.choice1.Label=='suma':
            self.button1.Label='SUMAR'
        if self.choice1.Label=='resta':
            self.button1.Label='RESTAR'
        if self.choice1.Label=='mult':
            self.button1.Label='MULT'
        event.Skip()

    def OnTextCtrl2SetFocus(self, event):
        self.textCtrl2.Value=''
        print self.choice1.Label
        if self.choice1.Label=='suma':
            self.button1.Label='SUMAR'
        if self.choice1.Label=='resta':
            self.button1.Label='RESTAR'
        if self.choice1.Label=='mult':
            self.button1.Label='MULT'
        event.Skip()

    def OnChoice1Choice(self, event):

        if self.choice1.Label=='suma':
            self.button1.Label='SUMAR'
        if self.choice1.Label=='resta':
            self.button1.Label='RESTAR'
        if self.choice1.Label=='mult':
            self.button1.Label='MULT'

        event.Skip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = create(None)
    frame.Show()

    app.MainLoop()
```

The print **self.choice1.Label** always print EMPTY in ubuntu, and in Windows print suma, resta or mul, one of the options of the wx.choice, how expected.

ricnar

Comment: BTW, you generally can replace points and sizes with tuples when callings wxPython functions.

Answer (score 2):

It's an error to use `self.choice1.Label`; replace it throughout your code with `self.choice1.StringSelection` and your code works!

Comment: But in windows Label works, if there are compatibility, must be work similar in ubuntu.

ricnar

Comment: I don't see Label documented as "working" (identically to StringSelection) in http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/ &c -- it may be a bug that it accidentally works in windows, or it may be a different version (I have 2.8.4). Fix your code to follow the documentation, as I just explained, and open a bug on the wx site if you care enough (I'm not a wx developer, I just try to help people).

Comment: Thanks.

And the ugly appearence with the fonts desfased and barely visible? Using StringSelection the windows looks similar to the image posted by me

ricnar

Comment: I don't particularly like the appearance of wx apps, either -- but, hey, that's part of why, by preference, I use PyQt instead;-) Anyway, depending on what fonts you have installed, you can definitely play around with fonts -- see http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Font-class.html and its links.